# Does try-catch from programming has any basis in formal logic or mathematics and if so what is it?

Tags: formal-theory

Does try-catch from programming has any basis in formal logic or mathematics and if so what is it?

Comment: This is about control flows in the automated execution of algorithms and might have some origin in formal proofs of algorithm correctness. But without more details, the question seems unsuitable for this site.

Comment: Procedural logic is different from formal logic, mainly because formal logic is atemporal and procedural logic is explicitly bound to time. the formal logic equivalent of this would be a mere 'or' statement: exists an error implying bug OR not exists an error implying continue. we can translate between them, but note that if we were to translate a computer program into a formal logic it would be one excruciatingly long statement incorporating al the possible outcomes of the program in a single sweep.

Comment: No. You can use functions called continuations to model the behavior of try-catch, but try-catch was invented to handle situations that are specific to real programming, such as when a server runs out of memory or a file that is supposed to exist doesn't. The server needs to keep going under these conditions. Formal languages don't have memory limits or external references like files, and there are no servers that have to keep going under unexpected conditions. Programming languages have a lot of features that are not found in formal languages.

Comment: There is a kind of indirect connection, because try/catch is a particular form of a programming feature often referred to as "call with current continuation". This feature corresponds to Peirce's law in logic, which in turn is equivalent to the law of excluded middle. This allows the Curry-Howard correspondence to extend to classical logic, when it was previously thought to be limited to intuitionistic logic.

Comment: There's parallel drawn between a Turing machine with TM-complete programming language that doesn't halt (if you don't catch the exception) for some input and an undefined result for that input in the corresponding partial recursive function. Kleene's Normal Form Theorem stating every partial recursive function can be rewritten into a normal form such that the minimization operator is used only once. By adding try/catch, you turn partial to total functions per Church-Turing thesis, otherwise it cannot be fully *represented* by any formal logic via Curry-Howard or its extension as it leads to ⊥.

Comment: Every program is a proof, so, yes. Plus, the conditional is literally logic.

Answer (score 3):

There are many connections between programming and formal logic. The [Curry-Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence) gives a direct relationship between computer programs and formal proofs.

Exception-handling, specifically, may be elegantly implemented using monads. See [this example in Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Exception). [Monads](https://www.futurelearn.com/info/courses/functional-programming-haskell/0/steps/27246) are a concept taken from category theory, a field in mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

At least superficially, proof-by-contradiction.

```
Assume (try) A  
but it leads to a contradiction (error)  
therefore (catch) not A
```

Like try-catch, the contradiction, which would be catastrophic in a general scope, is contained inside the assumption.

However, catch could technically contain arbitrary, unrelated code, whereas in the case of the assumption, the only legitimate place to go is "not A."

Answer (score 1):

A `try`-`catch` (or `try`-`except`)  construct is in the end no different from a classic `goto`.

It just tries to enforce a different semantics (via nomenclature and other mechanisms) – in fact, a *very, very* different semantics: a classic `goto` is about *normal* program flow; `try`-`catch` OTOH is about *abnormal* conditions.

But you can abuse exceptions to get the classic `goto`.

E. g. in Python:

```
class Goto(Exception):
    pass

try:
    for i in range(1,1000):
        if i % 2 == 0 and i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0 and i % 7 == 0:
            raise Goto(i)
except Goto as e:
    print(e)
```

You raise an exception *somewhere* and you catch it *somewhere else.*

It really *is* `goto`!